# Oracle SQL: select String which must alphabet letter(s)

Tags: sql, oracle

How to sort out string from a column that this string must have at least alphabet letter within, other than all numeric digits in oracle?

For example, it should be able to find out

```
"28473a22" or "23D987w"
```

but skip

```
"25618792" and "845179"
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from YourTable where regexp_like(col1, '[a-zA=Z]')
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3b06c/1/0)

Comment: Thank you, just curious if we what to find column string that only contains digits, I try select * from YourTable where regexp_like(col1, '[0-9,]') but it doesnt work...

Comment: @Dreamer - If you want to find strings that only contain digits, try: `select * from YourTable where regexp_like(col1, '^\d+$')`

Comment: Thanks every one for the perfect replies.